# Firestore rules. Deny update if array length is above 2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with some documents that all contain an array `players`

I would like to deny updating this array, if its length is above 2.

I tried

```
rules_version = '2';
to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /GameLobbies/{gameId} {
      
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }

      allow write, read: if isSignedIn();
      allow update : if resource.players.size() <= 2 //Doesn't work;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find anything about it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If anything I'd expect this to be `resource.data.players.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems that jump out:

1. The fields of a resource are under its `data` property.
2. The length of an array is in its `length` property I think.

So:

```
allow update : if resource.data.players.length <= 2
```

I also think you'll probably want to use `request.resource` as you're trying to [validate the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) as it'll be after the update.

So:

```
allow update : if request.resource.data.players.length <= 2
```

Comment: Hey thank you, Now I receive the error `FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: 
Type error. Received: [list] Expected: [map,path]. for 'update' @ L13`

Comment: When do you get that error? 1) when you try to save the rules? 2) when you run code against these rules? If #2, we'll need to see the code that triggers the error to be able to help.